# Dynamically blur slideshow content underneath div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blur

I'm having a hard time trying to find out how to pull this off, I've found a lot of resources for static images but none for things in motion.

I basically have a slideshow using jQuery Cycle and I'm looking to make the background parts of the overlaying div elements cause a blur effect on the slideshow directly underneath them. I only need this working in Chromium so overall browser compatibility isn't an issue.

Here is a JSFiddle to get a better idea: https://jsfiddle.net/9fy9yazc/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle.all.js'></script>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#background-scroll').cycle({ 
            fx: 'fade',
            pause: 0, 
            speed: "1000", //Time to fade into the next image [in milliseconds]
            timeout: "2000"  //Time spent on image [in milliseconds]
        });

    });

    </script>

    <style>
    #background-scroll { width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:-10;}

    .box {width: 40%; height: 100px; background: RGBA(255,255,255,0.4); border: 5px solid #FFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;}

    .box p {text-align: center; line-height: 25px; color: #FFF; font-size: 50px;}
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="background-scroll"><!-- Add Backgrounds in via PHP, all we need to do is add backgrounds into the backgrounds folder -->
        <img src='http://i.imgur.com/yd4bWi2.jpg' class='background' />
        <img src='http://i.imgur.com/n91n9rr.jpg?1' class='background' />
    </div>

    <div class="box blur">
        <p>Blur Behind this Element</p>
    </div>


    </body><!-- Closes off the HTML Document -->
</html>
```

Basically a dynamic version of Blur.js (http://www.blurjs.com/) which can be applied to everything rather than just background image elements.

Comment: if you post the code here too, that would help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just put a copy of the example in, it's basically just a little slideshow with two div elements put on top of it. I'm looking to be able to blur the slideshow only underneath the divs on top of it.

Comment: You may mess with the `style.opacity` of the div element, maybe using setInverval() for a _smooth_ blur. Is this any help?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm looking for something similar to blur.js: http://www.blurjs.com/ but which can be applied to the slideshow element. As blur.js just uses the background-image to fake the effect and isn't as dynamic as I was expecting it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?
**https://jsfiddle.net/9fy9yazc/4/**

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#background-scroll').cycle({ 
            fx: 'fade',
            pause: 0, 
            speed: "1000", //Time to fade into the next image [in milliseconds]
            timeout: "2000", //Time spent on image [in milliseconds]
            before: blur_it
        });

 function blur_it() {

     $('.box').css('background-image', 'url(' + this.src + ')');
     width=$('#background-scroll').width()+'px';
     height=$('#background-scroll').height()+'px';
     $('.box').css('background-size', width+ ' '+height);

}        

    });
```

Idea is to get current slideshow image, and to use it as a background for .box div (but in full size), and to apply blur filter to it... You will have to play with background-position (depending on .box position), but you can set it dynamically (with jQuery) too (little tweaking is needed).

Current values:

```
.box { -webkit-filter: blur(5px);

  filter: blur(4px);

margin:50px 0px 0px 60px;
 background-position: -80px -58px;
}
```

EDIT: **For complete synchronization**, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#background-scroll').cycle({ 
            fx: 'fade',
            pause: 0, 
            speed: "1000", //Time to fade into the next image [in milliseconds]
            timeout: "2000", //Time spent on image [in milliseconds]

        });

    $('.box').html($('#background-scroll').html());
   width=$('#background-scroll').width()+'px';
   height=$('#background-scroll').height()+'px';   
$('.box img').css('width',width);
$('.box img').css('height',height);   

//margin depends of your .box margin!!!
$('.box img').css('margin-left','-70px');  
$('.box img').css('margin-top','-55px');      


  $('.box').cycle({ 
            fx: 'fade',
            pause: 0, 
            speed: "1000", //Time to fade into the next image [in milliseconds]
            timeout: "2000", //Time spent on image [in milliseconds]

        });   


    });
```

DEMO: **https://jsfiddle.net/9fy9yazc/7/**

Idea is, again, simple, get slideshow html (images), get sizes, tweak position, hide biggest part of images outside .box (overflow:none)... and cycle it. :)

Comment: That's pretty close to what I was after, the only problem though was that I was looking to see if it was possible to make it animate in sync with the slideshow system. I think this is about as good as it's going to get though so thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Marcus, everything is possible. Check updated answer. ;)